# Different types of Cross shapes significance?

Tags: ritual

What is signified by different kinds of crosses? For example some graves have club(cards game) leaves type edges crosses, some graves have simple crosses?

Comment: Could you show a picture of the cross you are wondering about? It may just be ornamentation not unlike what would see adorning the calligraphy in the Quran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to the [Budded Cross](http://archive.is/0gSc2).

[image]

The article says,

> A cross with three circles or discs on each arm in a Christian context
>   represents the Holy Trinity but was probably also copied from earlier
>   Celtic Druidry, where the circles or rings represent the three
>   dominions of earth, sky and sea.
>
> There are several names for this cross, depending on the
>   interpretation. These include Budded, Apostles', or Cathedral Cross,
>   all implying a religious theme, and Treflée or Botonée1 in a heraldic
>   context.

And the [Christian Cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_cross), the best-known religious symbol of Christianity.

[image]

More crosses here on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross#As_emblems_and_symbols)

Comment: @WaqarAhmad As a Catholic, I'm not thrilled with this answer as it implies some sort of pagan influence on modern Christianity.  In any event, you could be seeing the cross found on the [St. Benedict Medal](http://www.osb.org/gen/medal.html) which is a sacramental used by Catholics for spiritual protection (a good and pious thing to have on tombstones)  It's more like a club than the budded cross (which commonly has a Corpus, making it a crucifix and not just a cross).